# Rails 4 - researches doesn't display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an app that list some "Tuto", and I want that the user could search  for any Tuto by categories or by keyword. It works like a charm for keyword but not for Categories...

Even if I select a category everything is still displayed...

Category were created in the console, 
like `Category.create(name: "Ruby")` and so on...

**This is my view index**

```
.container
  .row
    h1.text-gray Tutorials 
  .row.search_banner
    .col-xs-3
      =form_tag tutos_path, :method => 'get' do 
        =text_field_tag :search, params[:search],  placeholder:"Search by keywords"
        =submit_tag "Search", class:'btn btn-xs btn-default btn-search'


    .col-xs-3
      =form_tag tutos_path, :method => 'get' do 
        =select_tag :filter, options_for_select(Category.all.map{|c| c.name},  params[:filter])
        =submit_tag "Search", class:"btn btn-xs btn-default btn-search"

    .col-xs-3
      -if user_signed_in?
        = link_to "Create a tuto", new_tuto_path, class:"btn btn-success"
      br
      br    


#tutos.transitions-enabled
  -@tutos.each do |tuto|
    .box.panel-default
      = link_to image_tag(image_by_category(tuto.category.try(:name))), tuto_path(tuto)


      h3 = link_to tuto.title, tuto_path(tuto), class:"title-link"     
      h6 
        | Created by:
        span<>
        = tuto.user.full_name
      br
      span.glyphicon.glyphicon-heart
      span<>
      = tuto.get_upvotes.size
```

**model tuto**

```
class Tuto < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  validates :category_id, presence: true

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where(["title LIKE ?","%#{search}%"])
    else
      all
    end
  end
end
```

## edited the index action, not sure for the `elsif` are more logical?

**tutos controller**

```
class TutosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :set_tuto, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote]


  def index
   #binding.pry
    if params[:search] || params[:filter]
      @tutos = Tuto.search(params[:search]).includes(:user, :category)
    elsif params[:search].present?
      @tutos = Tuto.all.includes(:user, :category)
    elsif params[:filter].present?
      @categories = Category.search(params[:filter])
    else
      @categories = Category.all
    end
  end


  def show
    @tuto = Tuto.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.all
  end

  def new
    @tuto = Tuto.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create

    @tuto = Tuto.new(tuto_params)
    @tuto.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tuto.save
        flash[:success] = "Test"
        format.html { redirect_to @tuto, notice: 'Tuto was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tuto }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @tuto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tuto.update(tuto_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @tuto, notice: 'Tuto was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @tuto }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @tuto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @tuto.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tutos_url, notice: 'Tuto was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


  def upvote
    @tuto.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end


  private


    def set_tuto
      @tuto = Tuto.find(params[:id])
    end

    def tuto_params
      params.require(:tuto).permit(:title, :content, :id, :user_id, :category_id)
    end
end
```

#### I am not sure about my skills on using binding.pry but here is what I have when I simulate a selection of a category for exemple `AWS-Amazon`.

```
Started GET "/tutos?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=AWS-Amazon&commit=Search" for ::1 at 2016-09-28 03:30:19 +0200
Processing by TutosController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "filter"=>"AWS-Amazon", "commit"=>"Search"}

From: Tutos/app/controllers/tutos_controller.rb @ line 7 TutosController#index:

 6: def index
 =>  7:  binding.pry
     8:   if params[:search] || [:filter]
     9:     @tutos = Tuto.search(params[:search]).includes(:user, :category)
    10:   elsif
    11:     @tutos = Tuto.all.includes(:user, :category)
    12:   elsif
    13:     @categories = Category.search(params[:filter])
    14:   else
    15:     @categories = Category.all
    16:   end
    17: end

[1] pry(#<TutosController>)> params
=> {"utf8"=>"✓", "filter"=>"AWS-Amazon", "commit"=>"Search", "controller"=>"tutos", "action"=>"index"}
[2] pry(#<TutosController>)>
```

Why does my category filter doesn't give anything when my search by keyword works so well ?
Hoping for your help! Regards

**hummm My schema may help**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160920133801) do

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "image"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "tutos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  add_index "tutos", ["user_id"], name: "index_tutos_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.boolean  "admin"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "votable_id"
    t.string   "votable_type"
    t.integer  "voter_id"
    t.string   "voter_type"
    t.boolean  "vote_flag"
    t.string   "vote_scope"
    t.integer  "vote_weight"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "votes", ["votable_id", "votable_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_votable_id_and_votable_type_and_vote_scope"
  add_index "votes", ["voter_id", "voter_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_voter_id_and_voter_type_and_vote_scope"

end
```

Comment: Your `if` statement in the controller is (at least part of) your problem. The first branch will always execute because `|| [:filter]` is evaluating an array literal as truthy, and the rest of it is ignored. Change that to `|| params[:filter]` and you'll be a little closer, but you have multiple `elsif` expressions without any actual conditions -- it's entirely unclear what your logic is. I'd suggest you review [the basics of if statements](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/ifelse/) and make sure you know exactly what your code is doing.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my post, please let me know if it looks clearer ? cheers :)

Comment: Getting there! However, your first branch is still the only one which fires if params contains either `search` or `filter`. Remember that, in an `if` statement, only ONE branch will be executed -- the rest will not be, even if their condition is true. I think you actually want two if statements: one for the @tutos variable, and one for the @categories variable.

Comment: Can I have two if statement in the same action? I am not sure what to do here, please could you just give me another clue?

Comment: Yep. Two statements in a row, just like the two in your show action, will execute one after the other. I'm pretty sure that what you ultimately want to do is this: https://gist.github.com/rnubel/d202efd1f041d49bb2ae9c678cd0af24

Comment: okay ! It looks clearer, but now it throw me an undefined method `search' for #<Class:0x007fc0651d6910>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124402/discussion-between-nelly-johan-and-robert-nubel).