# rails4 - malformed format string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After [the correction of a wrong syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748221/undefined-method-filter-for-class0x007fc0600be140-edited-need-more-help-p/39748372?noredirect=1#comment66797749_39748372) I have a new error and I am not sure where it comes from:

**categories were created in the console**

```
 Category Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Category id: 1, name: "Ruby", created_at: "2016-09-26 09:03:17", updated_at: "2016-09-26 09:03:17">, #<Category id: 2, name: "Rails4", created_at: "2016-09-26 09:03:25", updated_at: "2016-09-27 14:32:39">, #<Category id: 3, name: "Rails5", created_at: "2016-09-26 09:03:30", updated_at: "2016-09-27 14:35:25">, #<Category id: 4, name: "Heroku", created_at: "2016-09-26 09:03:35", updated_at: "2016-09-27 14:35:47">, #<Category id: 5, name: "AWS-Amazon", created_at: "2016-09-26 09:03:43", updated_at: "2016-09-26 09:03:43">]>
```

**When I select:**

- "Ruby"       I have: `malformed format string - %R`
- "Rails4"     I have: `malformed format string - %R`
- "Rails5"     I have: `malformed format string - %R`
- "Heroku"     I have: `malformed format string - %H`
- "AWS-Amazon" I have: `too few arguments`

I am trying to filter my categories by name:

**category model**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tutos

  def self.filter(filter)
    if filter
      where(["name LIKE '%#{filter}%'"]).order('created_at DESC')
    else
      all
    end
  end
end
```

## 1st Edit

I've tried different way but I have issues in each:

```
`where(["name LIKE '%#{filter}%'"]).order('created_at DESC')`
```

**returns the malformed string alert**

```
`where("name LIKE '%#{filter}%'").order(created_at: :desc)`
```

**and**

```
`where("name LIKE ?", "%#{filter}%").order('created_at DESC')`
```

**return all the categories without filtering....**

you may want to see the  tutos/views/index

```
.container
  .row
    h1.text-gray Tutorials 
  .row.search_banner
    .col-xs-3
      =form_tag tutos_path, :method => 'get' do 
        =text_field_tag :search, params[:search],  placeholder:"Search by keywords"
        =submit_tag "Search", class:'btn btn-xs btn-default btn-search'

    .col-xs-3
      =form_tag tutos_path, :method => 'get' do 
        =select_tag :filter, options_for_select(Category.all.map{|c| c.name}, params[:filter])
        =submit_tag "Search", class:"btn btn-xs btn-default btn-search"

    .col-xs-3
      -if user_signed_in?
        = link_to "Create a tuto", new_tuto_path, class:"btn btn-success"
      br
      br    


#tutos.transitions-enabled
  -@tutos.each do |tuto|
    .box.panel-default
      = link_to image_tag(image_by_category(tuto.category.try(:name))), tuto_path(tuto)


      h3 = link_to tuto.title, tuto_path(tuto), class:"title-link"     
      h6 
        | Created by:
        span<>
        = tuto.user.full_name
      br
      span.glyphicon.glyphicon-heart
      span<>
      = tuto.get_upvotes.size
      br
      br
```

## 2nd edit

**Rails console log : if I search for "Heroku" Cartegory:
but as my categories belongs to tutos... ([Maybe have a look on the website filter are not online yet though but you will see the idea](https://duclostutos.herokuapp.com/tutos))**

Should I do something like this
`Tuto.category.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{filter}%").order('created_at DESC')`

```
Started GET "/tutos?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=Heroku&commit=Search" for ::1 at 2016-09-28 17:50:41 +0200
Processing by TutosController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "filter"=>"Heroku", "commit"=>"Search"}
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Tuto Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "tutos".* FROM "tutos"
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (1)
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" IN (2, 3, 5, 4, 1)
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = ? AND "votes"."votable_type" = ? AND "votes"."vote_flag" = ? AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 16], ["votable_type", "Tuto"], ["vote_flag", "t"]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = ? AND "votes"."votable_type" = ? AND "votes"."vote_flag" = ? AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 17], ["votable_type", "Tuto"], ["vote_flag", "t"]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = ? AND "votes"."votable_type" = ? AND "votes"."vote_flag" = ? AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 18], ["votable_type", "Tuto"], ["vote_flag", "t"]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = ? AND "votes"."votable_type" = ? AND "votes"."vote_flag" = ? AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 19], ["votable_type", "Tuto"], ["vote_flag", "t"]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = ? AND "votes"."votable_type" = ? AND "votes"."vote_flag" = ? AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 20], ["votable_type", "Tuto"], ["vote_flag", "t"]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = ? AND "votes"."votable_type" = ? AND "votes"."vote_flag" = ? AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 21], ["votable_type", "Tuto"], ["vote_flag", "t"]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = ? AND "votes"."votable_type" = ? AND "votes"."vote_flag" = ? AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 22], ["votable_type", "Tuto"], ["vote_flag", "t"]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = ? AND "votes"."votable_type" = ? AND "votes"."vote_flag" = ? AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 23], ["votable_type", "Tuto"], ["vote_flag", "t"]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = ? AND "votes"."votable_type" = ? AND "votes"."vote_flag" = ? AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 24], ["votable_type", "Tuto"], ["vote_flag", "t"]]
  Rendered tutos/index.html.slim within layouts/application (29.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_nav.html.slim (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 104ms (Views: 94.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

## 3rd Edit

**tuto model**

```
class Tuto < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  validates :category_id, presence: true


  def self.search(search)
    if search
     where(["title LIKE ?","%#{search}%"]).order('created_at DESC')
    else
      all
    end
  end
end
```

**category model**
I've build my category `filter` like the tuto `search`

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tutos

  def self.filter(filter)
    if filter
      #where(["name LIKE '%#{filter}%'"]).order('created_at DESC')
      #where("name LIKE '%#{filter}%'").order(created_at: :desc)
     where("name LIKE ?", "%#{filter}%").order('created_at DESC')
    else
      all
    end
  end
end
```

Checked with the suggested `raise 'check'`[image: I have this error:]

Feel free to ask for more code if needed, as I am not sure where I am wrong...
Many thanks
regards

Comment: would you mind pasting the Rails console log for the request ?, it might be possible the filter is empty. One more thing, hace you tried using `Category.filter` in the rails console ?, you could also check there and verify it is working. One more thing you could try is to do TDD, that way you write your test first and then write the code to fulfill your test, that way you're making sure everything works.

Comment: I've pasted the console log, I am not doing TDD right now... I have to learn that I know...

Comment: based on the rails console logs, your `like` query is not being executed, I don't see it there. Is your controller's code still the same as the one you have  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748221/undefined-method-filter-for-class0x007fc0600be140-edited-need-more-help-p/39748372?noredirect=1#comment66797749_39748372 ?

Comment: my controller is the same yes

Comment: are you trying to filter out tutos that belong to a category ?.

Comment: if you put `raise 'check'` inside the def.filter(filter) method, where it is executing the like query, does it actually ever make it into that piece of logic?  Where it is checking for `if filter`  I'm curious if it is making it there...

Comment: yes @fanta tutos has many category and a tuto belongs to a category

Comment: @Eric please see my 3rd edit I tried

Comment: I see what's going on here, the filter is there, and the code is actually getting into that `Category.filter` method, but we don't see it in the rails logs because you never use `@cateogires`, so, it stays as an `Arel` object and never executes de query. What you really need in your controller is to filter the `tutos` that belong to the given category, you would need to do something like `@tutos = Tuto.joins(:category).where('categories.name like....')` and there's where you pass the name of the given category in the `filter` param.

Comment: @fanta sorry If I sound nuts but  if I do this : `@tutos = Tuto.joins(:category).where('categories.name LIKE ?', "%#{filter}%").order('created_at DESC')`
it says `undefined local variable or method filter' for #<TutosController:0x007f926c30f1f0>` I don't really understand

Comment: `filter` is not defined in your controller, what you have in your controller is `params[:filter]`.

Comment: @fanta how should I define `filter`in my controller ? I add a `self.filter` in my model can u write a bit of code to help please ?

Comment: I will, let me try to think about it and I'll write it as an answer because it'll look better there.

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124473/discussion-between-nelly-johan-and-fanta).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it !

In my controller tutos I did this: 
many thanks to fanta who took me on the right way !

```
def index
  #binding.pry
    if params[:search].present?
      @tutos = Tuto.search(params[:search]).includes(:user, :category)
    else
      @tutos = Tuto.all.includes(:user, :category)
    end

    if params[:filter].present?
      @tutos = Tuto.joins(:category).where('categories.name LIKE ?', params[:filter])
    else
      @categories = Category.all
    end
  end
```

Comment: Good to know you found how to fix. And sorry for not posting the answer, I was writing it, but you know, I have work to do and many other things to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
where("name LIKE ?", "%#{filter}%").order('created_at DESC')
```